# Pasar datos de un table html a mysql desde jsp

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp

Saludos agradezco su gentil apoyo. Tengo una formulario para registrar productos q se van añadiendo a la tabla pero no tengo idea de como enviarlos al **mysql** dede **JSP**.

```
<form  id="detalle_boleta" class="form-horizontal" method="get" 
 action="Detalle_Ventas" role="form" autocomplete="off">     
     <div class="row">
 <!--Inicia Definicion Table -->                               
      <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#mytable").tablesorter();
              });
        </script>
    <h3>Detalle de Venta.</h3>
       <table class="tablesorter" id="mytable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Total</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: detalle_ventas ">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.fecha"> </td>
                   <td data-bind="text:$data.producto"> </td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.precio"> </td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.cantidad"> </td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.total"> </td>


                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>   
      </form>
 </div>         

<script type="text/javascript">
        function DetalleBoleta() {
            var self = this;

            //vector que guardara la informacion temporalmente 
             self.detalle_ventas = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.agregarproducto = function (){

                var fe = $('#txtfecha').val();
                 var pro = $('#cbxproducto').val();
                var pre = parseFloat($('#txtprecio').val());
                var cant = parseInt($('#txtcantidad').val());
                var tot=pre * cant;

                 alert("Producto Agregado");  
             self.detalle_ventas.push({fecha:fe, producto:pro, precio:pre, cantidad:cant,total:tot});


            };
             }
        ko.applyBindings(new DetalleBoleta());
    </script>
```

Comment: quieres mandar los datos que contiene la tabla html? osea convertirlos en un array?

Comment: y asi enviarlos?

Comment: De cualquier manera posible enviar el contenido si es posible de un array luego enviarlo a una base datos en mysql. Desde JavaNetbeans tengo mi pagina registra.jsp

Comment: para enviarlos yo usaría ajax revisa la documentación y como implementarlo para jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenas usamos la función `each` de **jquery** y por cada iteracion de `tr` creamos un `array` que al final agregamos con el método `push` y llenamos con cada valor dentro de los `td`.

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
$("#obtenerDatos").click(function(){
  var mytabla = []
  $("#mytable").find("tbody tr").each(function(index, el) {
    var tr = []
    $(this).find("td").each(function(index, el) {
       tr.push($(this).text())
    });
    mytabla.push(tr)
  });
  console.log(mytabla);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tablesorter" id="mytable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Total</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: detalle_ventas ">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.fecha">Valor 1</td>
                   <td data-bind="text:$data.producto">Valor 2</td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.precio">Valor 3</td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.cantidad">Valor 4</td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.total">Valor 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.fecha">Valor 6</td>
                   <td data-bind="text:$data.producto">Valor 7</td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.precio">Valor 8</td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.cantidad">Valor 9</td>
                    <td data-bind="text:$data.total">Valor 10</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="obtenerDatos" type="button" name="button">Obtener datos de Tabla</button>
```

Espero te ayude saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Excelente me ayuda, ahora tengo los capturado en la tabla pero como envío a la base de datos mysql [image: Detalle]